# Error de CSS, aplica estilo al elemento equivocado

Tags: html5, css3

Buenas esta es mi primera pregunta y espero hacerlo bien, estoy copiando una pagina web para practicar html y css, lo que me sucede es que al intentar poner el *background* azul de `page-section-2` en realidad se pone azul la `page-section-1` y no tengo idea de que puede si alguien me puede ayudar se aprecia, si no se me entiende la pregunta mis disculpas y si me dicen como mejorar se agradece

```css
html{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before,*:after{
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
 font-family: verdana, geneva, serif;
}
div.contenedor-body::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
/*--------Contenedor principal-------------*/
.contenedor-body{
  width: 1200px;/*80%*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2{
 text-align:center;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
.material-icons{
 font-size: 300%;
}

.material-icons{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.page-section-2{
  background-color: blue;
}

/*--------Contenedor principal-------------*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  /********PAGE SECTION 1*********/
  .colum-1{ 
  width:75%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 364px ;/*24%*/
  }
  .colum-2, .colum-3, .colum-4{
  width: 33.3%;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 15px%;/*15px*/
  padding-right:15px%;/*15px*/
    
  }
}
  /**********PAGE SECTION 2********/
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){

  div.col-A{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  }  

  div.col-B{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: -0.5%;
  padding-right: 15px;

  height: 1px; 
  padding-bottom: 1px;/*60%*/
  }

  div.col-C{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; 

  padding-bottom: 475px;/*15%*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cursos de Diseño Web - CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/stilos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenedor-body">
      <div class="top-banner">

       <!--PRIMERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->
      <header> 
        <div class="navegacion">
           <nav class="menu-principal">
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Inicio</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Empresa</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Servicios</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Productos</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Registro</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Contacto</a>
               </li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>   
        </header>
        <div class="page-section-1">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="columnas">
              <div class="colum-1">
                <h2>PACIFIC ALIANCE CAPITAL</h2>
                  <p>Con la inclusión de nuevas tecnologías y productos de inversión, pretendemos contribuir al desarrollo de dichos mercados siendo líderes de la industria del Trading e Inversiones.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-2">
                
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>
                 
                  <p>1-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-3">
                
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>
                  
                  <p>2-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-4">
               
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>  
                  <p>3-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

         <!--FIN DE LA PRIMERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

        <!--SEGUNDA SECCION SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

        <div class="page-section-2">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div>
              <h2>ASESORIAS A SU MEDIDA</h2>
              <p>En Pacific Alliance Capital brindamos asesorías personalizadas, adaptándonos día a día a los cambios de los mercados financieros. Si quiere lograr que su cartera de inversiones tenga óptimos resultados no dude en consultarnos.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-A">
              <div>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
                <h3>Informacion en tiempo real</h3>
                <p>Analizamos los mercados para ofrecer las mejores opciones de negociación.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
                <h3>Noticias y Analisis</h3>
                <p>Obtenga acceso a la totalidad de nuestros datos e informes del mercado.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-B">
              <img src="img/cellphone.jpg" alt="Imagen-de-aprobacion">
            </div>

           <div class="col-C">
            <div>
              <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
              <h3>Portafolio de Inversion</h3>
              <p>Negocie con nuestra amplia gama de instrumentos en cualquier mercado que desee.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
              <h3>Listo para comenzar</h3>
              <p>Proporcionamos las mejores condiciones de trading, la mayor velocidad de ejecución que se adaptan a sus necesidades.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div> 
        </div>

          <!--FIN DE LA SEGUNDA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

          <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->

        <div class="page-intermedio">
          <div class=contenedor">
            <div>
              <p class="pacific">Pacific Aliance Capital | Una gran oportunidad para invertir</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->
        
        <!--TERCERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->
        <div class="page-section-3">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div >
              <h2>POR QUE ELEGIRNOS</h2>
              <p>Le ofrecemos claridad, simplicidad y transparencia. Le ofrecemos formación y posibilidad de elegir Sus prioridades son nuestras prioridades. Y si necesita ayuda para cualquier cosa, estamos disponibles para ayudarle de inmediato. Trabajamos sin descanso para conseguir que sus operaciones le resulten más sencillas y ofrecerle una experiencia única al operar.</p>

              <p>El principal componente de Pacific Alliance Capital son nuestros clientes y el enfoque en sus necesidades. Ofrecemos servicios de calidad, además de un trabajo continuo en la mejora de las tecnologías, que nos ayudan a mantenernos en una posición líder en asesorias de mercados financieros.</p>
              <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
              <a href="#">Registrate</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--FIN DE LA TERCERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

         <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->

        <div class="page-intermedio-2">
          <div class=contenedor">
            <div>
              <p>ACCEDE A MAS DE 10.000 INSTRUMENTOS SUBYACENTES</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Fin de el Intermedio de la pagina-->
        
        <!--Contacto-->
        <div class="Contacto">
          <div>
            <div>
              <textarea name="Mensaje" id="Mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
              <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="text" name="Asunto" placeholder="Asunto">
              <input type="submit" value="enviar">
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p class="copyright">&copy;Copyright2018 Pacific Aliance  Capital | Todos los derechos reservados </p>
        <div class="navegacion">
          <nav class="menu-principal">
           <ul>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Inicio</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Empresa</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Servicios</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Productos</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Registro</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Contacto</a>
             </li>
           </ul>


         </nav>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Te falta usar la propiedad `clear`.

> Especifica en qué lados de un elemento flotante no se permite flotar.

Se te ponía el otro trozo azul porque el div flotaba en el de encima.

```css
html{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before,*:after{
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
 font-family: verdana, geneva, serif;
}
div.contenedor-body::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
/*--------Contenedor principal-------------*/
.contenedor-body{
  width: 1200px;/*80%*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2{
 text-align:center;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
.material-icons{
 font-size: 300%;
}

.material-icons{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.page-section-2{
clear:both;
  background-color: blue;
}

/*--------Contenedor principal-------------*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  /********PAGE SECTION 1*********/
  .colum-1{ 
  width:75%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 364px ;/*24%*/
  }
  .colum-2, .colum-3, .colum-4{
  width: 33.3%;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 15px%;/*15px*/
  padding-right:15px%;/*15px*/
    
  }
}
  /**********PAGE SECTION 2********/
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){

  div.col-A{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  }  

  div.col-B{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: -0.5%;
  padding-right: 15px;

  height: 1px; 
  padding-bottom: 1px;/*60%*/
  }

  div.col-C{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; 

  padding-bottom: 475px;/*15%*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cursos de Diseño Web - CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/stilos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenedor-body">
      <div class="top-banner">

       <!--PRIMERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->
      <header> 
        <div class="navegacion">
           <nav class="menu-principal">
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Inicio</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Empresa</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Servicios</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Productos</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Registro</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Contacto</a>
               </li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>   
        </header>
        <div class="page-section-1">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="columnas">
              <div class="colum-1">
                <h2>PACIFIC ALIANCE CAPITAL</h2>
                  <p>Con la inclusión de nuevas tecnologías y productos de inversión, pretendemos contribuir al desarrollo de dichos mercados siendo líderes de la industria del Trading e Inversiones.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-2">
                
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>
                 
                  <p>1-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-3">
                
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>
                  
                  <p>2-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="colum-4">
               
                  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">devices</i></a>
                  <h3>Acceso Mundial</h3>  
                  <p>3-Acceda a datos de mercado 24 horas al día y seis días a la semana para estar en conexión con todos los mercados internacionales.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

         <!--FIN DE LA PRIMERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

        <!--SEGUNDA SECCION SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

        <div class="page-section-2">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div>
              <h2>ASESORIAS A SU MEDIDA</h2>
              <p>En Pacific Alliance Capital brindamos asesorías personalizadas, adaptándonos día a día a los cambios de los mercados financieros. Si quiere lograr que su cartera de inversiones tenga óptimos resultados no dude en consultarnos.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-A">
              <div>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
                <h3>Informacion en tiempo real</h3>
                <p>Analizamos los mercados para ofrecer las mejores opciones de negociación.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
                <h3>Noticias y Analisis</h3>
                <p>Obtenga acceso a la totalidad de nuestros datos e informes del mercado.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-B">
              <img src="img/cellphone.jpg" alt="Imagen-de-aprobacion">
            </div>

           <div class="col-C">
            <div>
              <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
              <h3>Portafolio de Inversion</h3>
              <p>Negocie con nuestra amplia gama de instrumentos en cualquier mercado que desee.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <a href="#"><i class="material-icons2"></i></a>
              <h3>Listo para comenzar</h3>
              <p>Proporcionamos las mejores condiciones de trading, la mayor velocidad de ejecución que se adaptan a sus necesidades.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div> 
        </div>

          <!--FIN DE LA SEGUNDA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

          <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->

        <div class="page-intermedio">
          <div class=contenedor">
            <div>
              <p class="pacific">Pacific Aliance Capital | Una gran oportunidad para invertir</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->
        
        <!--TERCERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->
        <div class="page-section-3">
          <div class="contenedor">
            <div >
              <h2>POR QUE ELEGIRNOS</h2>
              <p>Le ofrecemos claridad, simplicidad y transparencia. Le ofrecemos formación y posibilidad de elegir Sus prioridades son nuestras prioridades. Y si necesita ayuda para cualquier cosa, estamos disponibles para ayudarle de inmediato. Trabajamos sin descanso para conseguir que sus operaciones le resulten más sencillas y ofrecerle una experiencia única al operar.</p>

              <p>El principal componente de Pacific Alliance Capital son nuestros clientes y el enfoque en sus necesidades. Ofrecemos servicios de calidad, además de un trabajo continuo en la mejora de las tecnologías, que nos ayudan a mantenernos en una posición líder en asesorias de mercados financieros.</p>
              <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
              <a href="#">Registrate</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--FIN DE LA TERCERA SECCION DE LA PAGINA-->

         <!--Intermedio de la pagina-->

        <div class="page-intermedio-2">
          <div class=contenedor">
            <div>
              <p>ACCEDE A MAS DE 10.000 INSTRUMENTOS SUBYACENTES</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Fin de el Intermedio de la pagina-->
        
        <!--Contacto-->
        <div class="Contacto">
          <div>
            <div>
              <textarea name="Mensaje" id="Mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
              <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="text" name="Asunto" placeholder="Asunto">
              <input type="submit" value="enviar">
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p class="copyright">&copy;Copyright2018 Pacific Aliance  Capital | Todos los derechos reservados </p>
        <div class="navegacion">
          <nav class="menu-principal">
           <ul>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Inicio</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Empresa</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Servicios</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Productos</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Registro</a>
             </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Contacto</a>
             </li>
           </ul>


         </nav>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh muchisimas gracias en serio no sabes lo mucho que me ha costado, te agradezco mucho